# How do I use Mathf.Min with a Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently when I crouch using a character controller and I am directly under a collider, my crouch key is disabled with `isCrouchingState = false;` but I want to still be able to crouch and uncrouch while under a collider, but at a reduced height since my player cannot fully stand up/uncrouch.

So I am using `Mathf.Min()` to find the amount of space between the head of my player and the collider above. I use the current controller height for my float value and also the hit distance:

```
float roomAboveAmount = controller.height; 
roomAboveAmount = Mathf.Min(roomAboveAmount, ceilingHit.distance);
```

The issue right now is I don't know where to try and place the `Mathf.Min` code. The `isCrouchingState = false;` is preventing my player from ever being able to crouch while under a collider but if I take it out then my player will just clip through the collider when standing up.

```
isCeilingAbove = Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.5f, Vector3.up, out RaycastHit ceilingHit, .5f);
if (isColliderAbove)
{
    isCrouchingState = false;
}
else
{
    // crouch code
    isCrouchingState = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
}
```

Comment: position is usually the characters feet, you arent even checking or limiting what you're hitting you could be hitting your character. so it will always be false